# Haskell pattern matching conundrum

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, prepend

I was trying to search through a list of pairs that could have the element ("$", Undefined) in it at some arbitrary location. I wanted to ONLY search the part of the list in front of that special element, so I tried something like this (alreadyThere is intended to take the element n and the list xs as arguments):

```
checkNotSameScope :: Env -> VarName -> Expr -> Expr
checkNotSameScope (xs:("$", Undefined):_) n e = if alreadyThere n xs then BoolLit False
                                                   else BoolLit True
```

But that does not work; the compiler seemed to indicate that (xs: ..) only deals with a SINGLE value prepending my list. I cannot use : to indicate the first chunk of a list; only a single element. Looking back, this makes sense; otherwise, how would the compiler know what to do? Adding an "s" to something like "x" doesn't magically make multiple elements! But how can I work around this?

Comment: Maybe I should ask, "How can I do it another way without pattern matching, since that's not possible?" Haskell is for very clever people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, even with smart compilers and languages, some programming cannot be avoided...

In your case it seems you want the part of a list up to a specific element. More generally, to find the list up to some condition you can use the standard library `takeWhile` function. Then you can just run `alreadyThere` on it:

```
checkNotSameScope :: Env -> VarName -> Expr -> Expr
checkNotSameScope xs n e = if alreadyThere n (takeWhile (/= ("$", Undefined)) xs)
                           then BoolLit False
                           else BoolLit True
```

It maybe does not what you want for lists where `("$", Undefined)` does not occur, so beware.

Comment: Or even `checkNotSameScope xs n e = BoolLit . not . alreadyThere n . takeWhile (/= ("$", Undefined)) $ xs`

Comment: Right. I was just fixing the code in question without reading too much of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Joachim's answer, you can use [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3abreak), which will allow you to detect when `("$", Undefined)` doesn't occur (if this is necessary). i.e.

```
checkNotSameScope xs n e = case break (== ("$", Undefined)) xs of
                             (_, [])  -> .. -- ("$", Undefined) didn't occur!
                             (xs', _) -> BoolLit . not $ alreadyThere n xs'
```

(NB. you lose some laziness in this solution, since the list has to be traversed until `("$", Undefined)`, or to the end, to check the first case.)

Answer (score 1):

Haskell cannot do this kind of pattern matching out of the box, although there are some languages which can, like [CLIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) for example, or F#, by using [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx).

But we can use Haskell's existing pattern matching capabilities to obtain a similar result. Let us first define a function called deconstruct defined like this:

```
deconstruct :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
deconstruct [] = []
deconstruct [x] = [([], x, [])]
deconstruct (x:xs) = ([], x, xs) : [(x:ys1, y, ys2) | (ys1, y, ys2) <- deconstruct xs]
```

What this function does is to obtain all the decompositions of a list xs into triples of form `(ys1, y, ys2)` such that `ys1 ++ [y] ++ ys2 == xs`. So for example:

```
deconstruct [1..4] => [([],1,[2,3,4]),([1],2,[3,4]),([1,2],3,[4]),([1,2,3],4,[])]
```

Using this you can define your function as follows:

```
checkNotSameScope xs n e =
    case [ys | (ys, ("$", Undefined), _) <- deconstruct xs] of
        [ys] -> BoolLit $ not $ alreadyThere n xs
        _    -> -- handle the case when ("$", Undefined) doesn't occur at all or more than once
```

We can use the [do-notation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad#Special_notation) to obtain something even closer to what you are looking for:

```
checkNotSameScope xs n e = BoolLit $ not $ any (alreadyThere n) prefixes
    where
        prefixes = do
            (xs, ("$", Undefined), _) <- deconstruct xs
            return xs
```

There are several things going on here. First of all the `prefixes` variable will store all the prefix lists which occur before the `("$", Undefined)` pair - or none if the pair is not in the input list `xs`. Then using the [any](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3aany) function we are checking whether `alreadyThere n` gives us True for any of the prefixes. And the rest is to complete your function's logic.

Comment: thanks! as is most often on SO, the proper answer, completely un-appreciated. SO is broken.  its voting system is bunk. it *looks* as if SO is knowledge curation system, it presents itself as such, but it is **not.**