# Haskell pattern matching char in a string

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a question on pattern matching:

Is it possible to somehow match a (string ++ [char] ++ anotherstring)?

I have tried something like:

```
f (s++";"++r) = s++r (the rhs is trivial, but its just for testing ;))
```

But this results in a parse error.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that a string containing multiple semicolons would make this ambiguous.  The solutions below assume you want to match the first semicolon, but in general, such a function would be non-deterministic, and should return a possibly empty list of results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Pattern matching deconstructs values according to the *constructors* they were built with, so you can only use constructor applications in pattern matching to describe which values match the pattern and which don't.

For something like your example, a `case` works well,

```
f str = case break (== ';') str of
          (s, _:r) -> s ++ r
          _        -> error "No semicolon found"
```

Comment: This question is asking for something that's almost a `String` literal counterpart to n+k patterns, the latter being a feature which was recently *removed* from the language. So not only is it impossible, the possibility of it becoming not-impossible is getting steadily less possible. Er, possibly.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake, one could make gratuitous use of GHC's `ViewPatterns` extension, and rewrite Daniel Fischer's example as something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

f (break (== ';') -> (s, _:r)) = s ++ r
f _ = error "No semicolon found"
```

This is of course a purely cosmetic change, but if you prefer the usual "group of equations" syntax instead of `case` expressions, there it is.

N.B. -- I don't have GHC at hand right now so I haven't actually tested the above.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. There are many functions in [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) which you can use to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of pattern matching similar to the way proposed here:

[Haskell pattern matching conundrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884674/haskell-pattern-matching-conundrum/12902898#12902898)